# get jButton position "deprecated" function

Tags: java, swing

I just want to ask you for the appropriate function for the button. BY using the function below, Eclipse notifies me that the function is "deprecated".

```
jButton.bounds();
```

My question to you is what is the right function to use if I want to get the position of the button?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There's always getBounds and getLocation, but I can't remember when I ever needed this functionality. Are you moving the button in some animation? If not, why need this?

Comment: yep it is a animation so i just nedd to move few buttons around when an action is trigged, thanks for the info

Comment: but the most important lesson to learn is to check the API. If a method is deprecated, 9 times out of 10 the API will tell you what to use instead, and in this case it does just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JButton.getBounds()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getBounds%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) is what you should be using instead.

Comment: Yes. @Michael: A *cursory* glance at the documentation would have revealed that: You go to the [JavaDoc for JButton](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html), search for `bounds`, and you find it under "Methods inherited from class `java.awt.Component`". Click the [handy link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#bounds()) and lo! *"Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by `getBounds()`."* Amazing.

Comment: quite funny that i did not spot that function in the object list, thanks for you help